# com.liferay.portal.kernel.job.JobExecutionException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed

Tags: postgresql, liferay

I used postgresql 9.3  and liferay 5.2

the system work correctly but after some time I have I have a connection loss problem in the log file.

```
(org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#6e2243fb_Worker-2) 07:19:09,914 ERROR [JobWrapper:81] com.liferay.portal.kernel.job.JobExecutionException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
com.liferay.portal.kernel.job.JobExecutionException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
    at com.liferay.counter.service.persistence.ConnectionHeartbeatJob.execute(ConnectionHeartbeatJob.java:55)
    at com.liferay.portal.job.JobWrapper.execute(JobWrapper.java:69)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:226)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:424)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:321)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:313)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.execute(NewProxyStatement.java:1006)
    at com.liferay.counter.service.persistence.ConnectionHeartbeatJob.sendHeartbeat(ConnectionHeartbeatJob.java:75)
    at com.liferay.counter.service.persistence.ConnectionHeartbeatJob.execute(ConnectionHeartbeatJob.java:52)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:143)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:112)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:70)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.ReceiveChar(PGStream.java:283)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1799)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:200)
    ... 9 more
2017-08-13 08:19:09,901 INFO  [STDOUT] (org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#6e2243fb_Worker-1) 08:19:09,901 WARN  [NewPooledConnection:486] [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
2017-08-13 08:19:09,903 INFO  [STDOUT] (org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#6e2243fb_Worker-1) 08:19:09,902 WARN  [NewPooledConnection:487] [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed. ] which will not be reported to listeners!
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.checkClosed(PgConnection.java:786)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createStatement(PgConnection.java:1598)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createStatement(PgConnection.java:405)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.createStatement(NewProxyConnection.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:364)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy261.createStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.counter.service.persistence.ConnectionHeartbeatJob.sendHeartbeat(ConnectionHeartbeatJob.java:73)
    at com.liferay.counter.service.persistence.ConnectionHeartbeatJob.execute(ConnectionHeartbeatJob.java:52)
    at com.liferay.portal.job.JobWrapper.execute(JobWrapper.java:69)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
2017-08-13 08:19:09,905 INFO  [STDOUT] (org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#6e2243fb_Worker-1) 08:19:09,903 ERROR [JobWrapper:81] com.liferay.portal.kernel.job.JobExecutionException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
com.liferay.portal.kernel.job.JobExecutionException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
    at com.liferay.counter.service.persistence.ConnectionHeartbeatJob.execute(ConnectionHeartbeatJob.java:55)
    at com.liferay.portal.job.JobWrapper.execute(JobWrapper.java:69)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.checkClosed(PgConnection.java:786)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createStatement(PgConnection.java:1598)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createStatement(PgConnection.java:405)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.createStatement(NewProxyConnection.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:364)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy261.createStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.counter.service.persistence.ConnectionHeartbeatJob.sendHeartbeat(ConnectionHeartbeatJob.java:73)
    at com.liferay.counter.service.persistence.ConnectionHeartbeatJob.execute(ConnectionHeartbeatJob.java:52)
    ... 3 more
```

this is my configuration in **portal-ext.properties** :

```
#
# PostgreSQL
#
jdbc.default.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.2.3:5432/portal
jdbc.default.username=postgres
jdbc.default.password=postgres
```

and I try to add these lines but the error still appear :

```
jdbc.default.testConnectionOnCheckout=true
jdbc.default.preferredTestQuery=SELECT 1
jdbc.default.acquireIncrement=1
jdbc.default.maxIdleTime=10800
jdbc.default.maxConnectionAge=14400
jdbc.default.numHelperThreads=20
```

I cannot understand the error,
Can be problem in  postgresql setting or in connection pool setting in liferay

I have this line in **postgresql.conf** which can be changed to solve this problem :

```
#synchronous_standby_names = '' # standby servers that provide sync rep
                # comma-separated list of application_name
                # from standby(s); '*' = all
```

**Updated :**

This error is displayed in log file in several times,  but the first appear is after some minute maybe take 1 hour.

I run Postgresql in docker container.

liferay and database container are in the same Physical server.

I don't know why the database connection is unreachable for some times.

this is the docker version :

```
 docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 10 21:20:36 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 10 21:21:56 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Comment: I am having similar issue. How did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, Liferay 5.2? That's been a while...

The first question is: Does this appear often/every time? Can you reproduce it or was it just once? One common reason for this to happen is, when Postgresql is updated and restarts. If this happens during a transaction, I hope that Postgresql shuts down gracefully, e.g. finishes a transaction before shutting down.

On the other hand, before it starts up again, it will be unreachable for some time. Even when Liferay (or the connection pool) determines that the current connection is invalid (see the testQuery), it won't be able to reconnect during the time the server is down. And if Postgresql runs on a different server than the one where Liferay runs on, it can not only be a restart of the database itself, it might be a full OS-reboot. Naturally, Liferay will lose the connection during this time.

As you don't give any other indication on steps to reproduce, I'd say that this is a good starting guess. Otherwise more information is required.

Comment: thanks for your response, I have updated my question , I used database container  , I think that postgreSQL has no problem to be used with Docker, This error is displayed in log file in several times, but the first appear is after some minute maybe take 1 hour.